# How to extract a list of anchor tag text within a class and append each text to different list using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a list of anchor tag text within a class and append each text to different list using beautifulsoup as follows.

```
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x11">comment1</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x21">comment2 </a>
</p>
<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x31">comment3</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x41">comment4 </a>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
data1 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "comments"})    

x1 = []
x2 = []
    
for data in data1:
     get_a = data.find_all("a")
     text = ""
     for i in get_a:
         text = i.text
         x1.append(text)
         x2.append(text)
print(x1)
print(x2)
```

I get the following results:

```
['comment1', 'comment2 ', 'comment3', 'comment4 ']
['comment1', 'comment2 ', 'comment3', 'comment4 ']
```

But, I would like to get the desired output as follows:

```
x1= ['comment1', 'comment3']
x2= ['comment2', 'comment4']
```

I appreciate you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
data1 = soup.find("p", {"class": "comments"}).find_all('a')   
data2 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "comments"})[1].find_all('a')   

x1 = []
x2 = []

for data in data1:
    x1.append(data.text)
for data in data2:
    x2.append(data.text)

print(x1)
print(x2)
```

Output:

```
['comment1', 'comment2 ']
['comment3', 'comment4 ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make list of list and then append data to it.It has advantage of being scalable.

```
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x11">comment1</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x21">comment2 </a>
</p>
<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x31">comment3</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x41">comment4 </a>
</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
data1 = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "comments"})    

x = []
for data in data1:
    get_a = data.find_all("a")
    text = []
    for i in get_a:
        text.append(i.text)
    x.append(text)
```

Output

```
[['comment1', 'comment2 '], ['comment3', 'comment4 ']]
```

If you want as 2 separate list you can do something like this

```
x1,x2 = x
print(x1,x2)

['comment1', 'comment2 '], ['comment3', 'comment4 ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to add comments to a list in chunks of two, so here's a way to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x11">comment1</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x21">comment2 </a>
</p>
<p  class="comments">
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x31">comment3</a>, 
<a href="/search/?searchtype=name1$amp; query=x41">comment4 </a>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser").find_all("a")


def chop(l: list, n: int = 2):
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]


def get_comments(anchors: list):
    return [anchor.text for anchor in anchors]


for comments in chop(get_comments(soup)):
    print(comments)
```

This yields:

```
['comment1', 'comment2 ']
['comment3', 'comment4 ']
```